# LidGDX. How to load .G3D(binary) model with animation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I use lidGDX for android app. I have an animated blender model exported to G3D binary format. According to all docs I should use code like

```
AssetManager assets;

assets.load("data/mymodel1.g3d", Model.class);
Model model = assets.get("data/mymodel1.g3d", Model.class);
```

But this only works when you have JSON-based models. All loaders AssetManager has are for JSON files. There is no loader for binary data. But libGDX says that binary format G3D is supported. I can't find a way to load the binary model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old g3d file format isn't used anymore (AssetManager has never been able to load .g3d files). It is replaced by the new G3DB (binary json) and G3DJ (textual json) file format. You can use fbx-conv (https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) to convert FBX models to one of these file formats. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/.